# input textfile lines in excel

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to multiple files 1 by 1 using a while loop to rin through all the text file names in Column A. The loop seems to work however it only inputs the data found in the first file. it inputs the data against each of the file names as though it is opening the same file each time. I have run through the code step by step and can see the 'CurrFile' updating during the loop but can't figure out why it is only returning the data from the first text file listed in column A.

I have tried a few different methods and the below is the closest I have got so far:

```
Sub ReadFileLineByLine()

Dim my_file As Integer
Dim text_line As String
Dim file_name As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim CurrFile As String
Dim RowCount As Long

Sheets("Log").Activate


RowCount = 1

While Range("A" & RowCount).Value <> ""

CurrFile = Range("A" & RowCount).Value

file_name = "S:\NHHDC\working\Sean F\Adhoc Projects\UG_DUP_D0010s\" & CurrFile
my_file = FreeFile()
Open file_name For Input As my_file


Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
    text = text & textline
Loop

Close #1

postMPAN = InStr(text, "026|")
postMSN = InStr(text, "028|")
postRead = InStr(text, "030|")

Range("B" & RowCount).Value = Mid(text, postMPAN + 4, 13)
'Range("C" & RowCount).Value = Mid(Text, postMSN + 4, 10)
Range("C" & RowCount).Value = Mid(text, postRead + 6, 16)

RowCount = RowCount + 1
'Close my_file

Wend

End Sub
```

I would expect the results returned for each file to be different but the data that is input into the adjacent columns are always from the first file.

any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I dont't have a lot of experience with reading textfiles, but as far as I understand it you should replace `#1` with `my_file`: `Line Input my_file, textline` and `Close my_file`. Since you open the file `As my_file`, not as `#1`

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have made the changes you have suggested but I get the same issue. The process runs but returns the same results against each file name.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with `F8` to see if the correct files are being opened and closed?

Comment: in addition to @M. Schalk comment, another issue may causing problem that variable `text` is to be reset  or re-initialized to `text=""` after opening file and before `Do Until EOF(my_file)` loop. Now 'text` is being concatenate and the 1st section form 1st file always same.

Comment: Thanks all! I changed all #1 to my file and added the text ="" before and after the Do Until loop. This runs perfect now and I get the expected results! thanks again for all your input.